# Event listener seems not to be listening or getting the necessary/expected values

Tags: javascript

Event listener isn't receiving any meaningful data.  Complicated to explain. I click a "function button" in my page - which fires off an ajax request and loads a form into a div on the page called 'ajaxDiv'.

When I submit that form, I want to use e.preventDefault() and for the event listener to get the form data ie, the values entered to each form field.  So far I only get the specific input field ID but not the others and none of the values entered to the form.

Below is the listener so far.

console.log(); seems to show that only the id of the form is being returned.  Not any IDs of the form fields and none of the data entered to the form.

```
document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var record_id = e.target.id;
    var target = e.target;

    console.log( 'target  =    ' + target);
    console.log( 'record_id   ' + record_id );

    if ( record_id ) {
        if ( record_id === email_address1 ) {
            var email_address1 = e.target.id;
        }
    }
 });
```

The value returned to the console is "start_layaway_form"

The form html is next.

```html
<div id='initiate-layaway-form'>
  <form id='start_layaway_form'>
    <input type='hidden' name='order_function' value='initiate-layaway' />
    <input type='hidden' name='order_id' value="$order_id" />
    <input type='hidden' name='business_id' value="$business_id" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Enter email address</p>
          <label for='email_address1'></label>
          <input type='text' id='email_address1' name='email_address1' placeholder='Enter email address' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Re-enter email address</p>
          <input type='text' id='email_address2' name='email_address2' placeholder='Re-enter email address' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>OR</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Enter Post Code</p>
          <input type='text' id='post_code' name='post-code' placeholder='Enter Post Code' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Enter House Number</p>
          <input type='text' id='house_number' name='house-number' placeholder='Enter House Number' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Start Layaway' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, with my form already generated by ajax, and pushed into the div "ajaxDiv", I want to capture the values entered to the form in the listener so I can input those values to my database, again, via ajax.

Can't yet seem to grasp the listener concept. :(

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Bazz

Comment: I assume you need to catch the submit event at the form.

Comment: I don't understand your end result in mind. Your code just sets email_address to itself, if the id is the same?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `document.getElementById("start_layaway_form").addEventListener("submit"...`  ? I assume you want to capture the submit of your form, not the submit of a div element.

Comment: Since you won't actually use the default submitting behaviour of a form ( you don't have an url to POST the form to ), might as well use a normal button with a click event instead of a submit button so you don't have to worry anymore about preventDefault() and such to highjack the normal submit behaviour. And if the id's or names of the input fields are always these names ( email_address1, house-number, etc ), just select the nodes by id manually,  and ask for their `.value`. Alternatively, use a `FormData()` object and just pass it the form itself.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I tried re-naming the 'ajaxDiv' to 'start_layaway_form'  but got a new error message in the console.  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' "   And when I submit the form it operates as if e.preventDefault() were disabled.

Comment: @headache You don't have to rename the ajax div, the `start_layaway_form` was the id of your form so you only had to change the javascript code to get the submit event from that form the way I wrote before. The id of the div doesn't matter and should not be the same as the one of the form as it should be unique

Comment: Thanks Shilly...  Some reading to do.  Quite new to js so your response is quite a bit over my head :(

Comment: Thanks Jeprubio...I only changed what your post suggested.  Not the name of the div itself.  I wonder if the issue is partly due to the form being ajax created on the fly?  It's not a hard coded form that I want to capture data from.

Comment: Blimey..I wasn't even close to thinking I could call in address1 like this..." var email_address1 = e.target.email_address1.value;
"   Thanks for the push :)